# How to Highlight row based on particular value in the table?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ighK51xebI&t=219s) that works on Google App Script and Google Sheets

I want to highlight the row if it contains the value "ABSENT", I tried many ways to but ended in failures,

Need some assistance to modify this code to do the job

NOTE: Updated the code for better understanding.

CODE.JS

```
function doGet(e) {
  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate()
  .setTitle("WebApp: Search By Password")
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){ 
  var concat = formObject.searchtext+formObject.searchtext2;
  var result = "";
  if(concat){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(concat);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS ;
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = '1bahNEJIweyuvmocYbSR8Nc_IA_HP3qdO7tCKU6w'; //** CHANGE !!!!
  var sheetName = "Data"
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
  var data = range.getDisplayValues();
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~[f[8]].indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push([ f[2],f[3],f[4],f[5],f[6],f[7] ]);
    }
  });
                                           
  return ar;
};
```

INDEX.HMLT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_self">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
       
   <style>
   
   /* h5 {background: red;} */
   
   </style>

        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  <center><form id="search-form" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                      <h5 for="searchtext">Work Log Records</h5>
                    </div><p>
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-3">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control col-sm-6" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" placeholder="Email"  required><br>
                  
                      <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" id="searchtext2" name="searchtext2" placeholder="Employee ID"  required>
                    </div><p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" >Generate
                      <span id="resp-spinner5" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                    </button>
                    
                    
                 
                  </form></center>
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END ------------------------------------------- -->
              
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------------ -->
                <div id="search-results" class="table table-responsive ">
                  <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
                </div>
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        <script>
          //PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
          function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
              forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true);
             
          
          
          //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
           if(document.getElementById('searchtext').value == "" || document.getElementById('searchtext2').value == ""){
              alert("Fill in Email and Employee ID");
           }else{
             document.getElementById('resp-spinner5').classList.remove("d-none");
        
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
            document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
           };
          };
        
          //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
          
          function createTable(dataArray) {
             document.getElementById('resp-spinner5').classList.add("d-none");
   
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-dark table-hover' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                             "<tr >"+                               //Change table headings to match with the Google Sheet
                              
                              "<th scope='col'>EMPLOYEE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>DATE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>IN TIME</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>OUT TIME</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>HOURS</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>STATUS</th>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                          "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
              result += "</table>";
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = result;
            }else{
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              //div.empty()
              div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
            }
          }
        </script>
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ~ END ---------------------------------------------------- -->    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `I want to highlight the row`? For example, you want to set the background of the row including the value of `ABSENT` to the red color or other color?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for the response, I want to set  the colour including  of the value 'ABSENT' in the row.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying of `The webapp is set to have a user login in order to fetch the user details based on the user login info. After I added your code, the webapp disappears from the sight,`, in this case, it seems that your current issue is different from your this question. So, I think that my answer is not useful for your situation. My answer just sets the background color of row when the value of `ABSENT` is included in the row. By this, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Please keep your answer, So that i can play around with your code and try something may work. Can you please add back your code. and Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that unfortunately, my proposed answer cannot resolve your current issue of `The webapp is set to have a user login in order to fetch the user details based on the user login info. After I added your code, the webapp disappears from the sight,`. In this case, I think that your question cannot be resolved. So, when I could correctly understand about your current issue, I would like to reopen my answer including both solutions.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm absolutely sorry, I made mistake by adding your code in wrong place, after placing the correct place, the login and table appears perfectly, but it doesn't highlight the row. this is the code your provided, 'for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
          result += dataArray[i].some(c => c.toUpperCase() == "Leave") ? '<tr style="background-color:red;">' : "<tr>";
          for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
          result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
          }'

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about your current situation. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation? By this, I would like to try to understand it. For example, can you provide your whole script for replicating your current issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I've updated my original post with full code, please check!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. When I saw your script, my proposed script is not used. I think that the reason of your currrent issue is due to this. How about this? And, although I cannot understand about your value of `dataArray`, if you use my proposed script and the values don't includ the value of `ABSENT`, the background color is not set. Please be careful this.

Comment: For example, in order to check the value of `dataArray`, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232795/discussion-between-muhammed-aadhil-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 0):

I guess `dataArray[i][j]` is where "Absent" can be.

In this case, you are basically looking for an existence of a string("Absent") inside another string(`dataArray[i][j]`)

thats where you use search() method.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

Some code as below will work.

```
if (dataArray[i][j].search("ABSENT") > -1){
  /*change color to red or whatever*/
}
```

Comment: That is a bad comment. If you want a problem solved, you better tell me which part didnt work.
Is dataArray[i][j] where "ABSENT" is expected? or is it somewhere else?

Comment: Apologies,  I'm not  a coder to understand the coding language. I copy and replaced your solution code`if (dataArray[i][j].search("ABSENT") > -1){
  Red
}` that's all i know :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell given code has nothing to do with Google Spreadsheet. It looks like some Javascript code that makes an HTML-table for a web browser.

But how exactly this HTML-table will get into Google Spreadsheet? Manually via copy and paste?

Since they can be two very different task:

-- to change color of cells in the original HTML-table (but the colors may disappear after putting it on Google Spreadsheet via system clipboard).

-- to change color of cells in Google Spreadsheet table (but firstly the table should to get there somehow, how?).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to set the background color of the row when the row has the value of `ABSENT`.

In this case, how about checking whether the value of `ABSENT` is included in each row? When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
    result += "<tr>";
    for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
        result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
    }
    result += "</tr>";
}
```

#### To:

```
for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
  result += dataArray[i].some(c => c.toUpperCase() == "ABSENT") ? '<tr style="background-color:red;">' : "<tr>";
  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
    result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
  }
  result += "</tr>";
}
```

- In this case, the row which has the value of `ABSENT` is set as the red background color. If you want to change the color, please modify above script.

#### Note:

- If you want to set the background color for only the cells instead of the row, you can also use the following modification.

  ```
    for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
      result += "<tr>";
      for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
        result += (dataArray[i][j].toUpperCase() == "ABSENT" ? '<td style="background-color:red;">' : "<td>") +dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
      }
      result += "</tr>";
    }
  ```

### Added:

From your following replying,

> @Tanaike I'm absolutely sorry, I made mistake by adding your code in wrong place, after placing the correct place, the login and table appears perfectly, but it doesn't highlight the row. this is the code your provided, 'for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) { result += dataArray[i].some(c => c.toUpperCase() == "Leave") ? '' : ""; for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){ result += ""+dataArray[i][j]+""; }'

It seems that you are testing the script using the value of `Leave`. In your question, the value is `ABSENT`. If you want to change the values to `Leave`, please modify above script as follows. Because `toUpperCase()` converts the characters to the upper case.

#### From:

```
for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
    result += "<tr>";
    for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
        result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
    }
    result += "</tr>";
}
```

#### To:

```
for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
  result += dataArray[i].some(c => c == "Leave") ? '<tr style="background-color:red;">' : "<tr>";
  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
    result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
  }
  result += "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, i tried to login but the webapp dissapeared. If i haven't explained my issue in the post, pls take look at the link. i've added the login details below the script you've given 
https://script.google.com/home/projects/1ZopOuBl3bWuCrcwnO-WCMmSACYeNEOCsZwoQnyVYYfHq65meD_zkYpmE/edit

Comment: @Muhammed Aadhil Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `i tried to login but the webapp dissapeared.`. Because my proposed modification is only check the values and set background color of rows. Unfortunately, I cannot understand it. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: The webapp is set to have a user login in order to fetch the user details based on the user login info. After I added your code, the webapp disappears from the sight, If you need furhter clarification, please ask, and thank you for your help.

Comment: @Muhammed Aadhil Thank you for replying. From your replying of `The webapp is set to have a user login in order to fetch the user details based on the user login info. After I added your code, the webapp disappears from the sight,`, in this case, it seems that your current issue is different from your this question. So, I think that my answer is not useful for your situation. My answer just sets the background color of row when the value of `ABSENT` is included in the row. By this, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Muhammed Aadhil From `I made mistake by adding your code in wrong place, after placing the correct place, the login and table appears perfectly`, I understood that the issue of `The webapp is set to have a user login in order to fetch the user details based on the user login info. After I added your code, the webapp disappears from the sight` was resolved. I thought that in this case, my proposed script might be able to be used. So, I reopened my answer.